# "Missing configuration resource for path" to struts config file

Tags: java, struts-1

Please note, this has been solved by clearing caches in intelliJ. All the code was correct, just an invalid state had been cached in the IDE.

---

This is driving me crazy. We're using struts 1, fyi.

My struts config file is called struts-config-mexp.xml. I have configured web.xml to point to the file in WEB-INF/struts dir, like so:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServicesManagerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.pronto.common.manager.ServicesManagerServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Standard Action Servlet Configuration (with debugging) -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts/struts-config-mexp.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>detail</param-name>
        <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

The file is definitely in the struts dir under WEB-INF. Here's part of the dir structure:

```
src/
  main/
    java/
    resources/
    webroot/
      WEB-INF/
        struts/
          struts-config-mexp.xml
        web.xml
```

I've tried moving the file to other locations (and changing the location in web.xml), e.g., in src/main/resources, but no matter where I put it I get this failure.

```
16:35:13,856  INFO ContextLoader:301 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 976 ms
16:35:13,859  INFO GlobalRootManager:85 - Entering initialization
16:35:14,095  INFO GlobalRootManager:85 - Exiting initialization
16:35:14,104  INFO FileUtil:223 -  -> Found /services-mgr.properties in resource bundle
16:35:14,126 ERROR ActionServlet:731 - Missing configuration resource for path /WEB-INF/struts/struts-config-mexp.xml
```

UTA: I also tried creating a classes dir under WEB-INF and moving the struts config file there, but that didn't work either.

I'm hoping it's just some dumbass mistake I can't see now because I've been staring at it for too long. Thanks.

Comment: Check the real content of the war file deployed to the container. Not just your source directories.

Comment: In desperation finally, in intelliJ, I did File->Invalidate Caches. When iJ restarted, it was able to find and load my config file. @$#*&%!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming following things: 
- struts-config-mexp.xml is present at the designated location
- servlet mappings are in place in web.xml

You can try following to get that struts file loaded:

1. move it adjacent to web.xml and change the configuration path in web.xml accordingly
2. mention in the classpath settings in your project, ideally in war's manifest.
3. make the load on startup of actionservlet to 1

Comment: All good suggestions, thanks. Not sure whether you saw my comment on the question, above, but intelliJ's File->Invalidate Caches is what it took to get things working. Sometimes iJ gets a wrong state cached and that's the only thing that fixes an otherwise quite correctly coded situation.